# Does there exist a surjective group homomorphism $\varphi:A_4\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Does there exist a surjective group homomorphism $\varphi:A_4\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Edit: I have narrowed it down to the problem of whether $A_4$ has a normal subgroup of order 3 with 3-cycles as elements:

From the theorem of group homomorphism if $\varphi$ is a homomorphism then the $\operatorname{ker}(\varphi)$ has to be normal. From the isomorphism theorem the quotient group $A_{4} / \operatorname{ker}(\varphi)$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ (If the kernel is normal). Since $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ has order 4, we know that $A_{4} / \operatorname{ker}(\varphi)$ also has order 4 (since they're isomorphic). From lagranges theorem we can then conclude that $|\operatorname{ker} \phi|=\frac{\left|A_{n}\right|}{\left|A_{4} / \operatorname{ker} \phi\right|}=\frac{12}{4}=3$.
Since 3 is a prime and the order of a group element divides the order of the group, we know that the elements of the kernel must have order 3 (Not order 1, since all 1 cycles are the identity element). So the kernel has to be the group consisting of three 3-cycles from $A_4$.

Comment: Hint: what might be the kernel of such homomorphism?

Comment: @Mark I don't think I can say too much of what the kernel. Only that it has to be a normal subgroup of $A_4$

Comment: @Mark Okay, I think I figured something out. From the theorem of group homomorphism then if $\varphi$ is homomorphism then the $ker(\varphi)$ has to be normal. From the isomorphism theorem then the quotient group $A_4/ker(\varphi)$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$ has order 4, we know that $A_4/ker(\varphi)$ also has order 4 (since they're isomorphic). From lagranges theorem we can then conclude that $|\operatorname{ker} \phi|=\frac{\left|A_{n}\right|}{\left|A_{4} / \operatorname{ker} \phi\right|}=\frac{12}{4}=3$.

Comment: How many elements does the kernel have?

Comment: since 3 is a prime and the order of a group element divides the order of the group we can say that the elements of the kernel must have order 3. So the kernel has to be the group consisting of 3 cycles in $A_4$

Comment: Correction: The kernel has to be a group consisting of 3 3-cycles. --

There are 8 3-cycles in $A_4$. So there must be $8\cdot7\cdot6 /3 =112$ different groups with 3 3-cycles from  $A_4$ (If I'm counting correct?). So how do I verify that none of them is normal, without checking 112 groups? (if there doesn't exist a group homomorphism). And if there exists a homomorphism, is it enough to just find one normal group?

Comment: @Berci, is my above analysis somehow correct? and how do I proceed from here?

Comment: @hh25 Yes, and does $A_4$ have normal subgroups of order $3$?

Comment: @Mark I really have no idea? My book doesn't mention anything about normal subgroups of $A_n$. I also don't think there are any theorems that relate the order of a group and the order of normal subgroups (I don't think they're generally related in any way). Is there a reason why $A_4$ must/can't have normal subgroups of order 3?

Comment: Let me suggest that in order to forestall further close votes, you read our guidelines for how to avoid [I have no clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and then you edit your question to include the attempts that you have worked out so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\varphi: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, then given any element $a \in G$, we know that $\text{ord}(a)$ is a multiple of $\text{ord}(f(a))$.

Now we recall little background on the symmetric group $S_4$ and its subgroup $A_4$. The group $S_4$ has elements of cycles: 1-cycle, 2-cycle, 3-cycle, 4-cycles and product of two 2-cycles. Thus the possible orders of the elements of $S_4$ are $1,2,3,4$. But it is a fact that $A_4$ don't have an element of order $4$. So the possible orders of elements of $A_4$ are $1,2,3$.

If there is a surjective homomorphism  $\varphi: A_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_4=\{\bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2, \bar 3\}$. There exists some $a \in A_4$ such that $\varphi(a)=\bar 3$. Thus by the first sentence above, $\text{ord}(a)$ would be a multiple of $\text{ord}(\varphi(a))=\text{ord}(\bar 3)=4$, which is not possible, since $a \in A_4$ can not have order $4$. Thus there is no such surjective homomorphism.

Comment: This is a nice way to show it. However, the initial fact that ord(f(a)) divides ord(a) for a group homomorphism is not something I have seen before (is not mentioned in my book or any exercises) and thus not something I would come up with. But I will try to see if I can prove this myself.

Comment: @hh25, thanks. It is a very basic property of group homomorphism. It should be found in any textbook covering group homomorphism. The proof is also simple. [Look here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Homomorphic_Image_of_Group_Element)